# fixed navigation bar overlaying content when position is given dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a one page website with multiple sections. my problem is that once I click on a link in the navigation bar it scrolls to the item but covers part of the content.

the navigation is only given static positioning when scrolling past its original position (Hope that makes sense). here is a link to my dev site http://wp.matthewwood.me/

here is my code for adding the fixed positioning using JQuery. i tried offsetting it by -50px to accommodate for the fixed nav size but this has not solved the problem.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var offset = $(".navbar").offset().top;     
   $(window).scroll(function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
             $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');

         }
         else {
             $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
         }
    });

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50}, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change from relative to fixed positioning, the block value of the div changes from it's height to zero. This causes the offset issue you are experiencing. See this fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/7muk9zhh/5/

The main things that have changed:

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        $("#Main").css("margin-top", $(".navbar").height()); //Compensates for fixed positioning
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        $("#Main").css("margin-top", "");
    }
});

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var globOffset = $(".navbar").height(); //Acts as an offset for the fixed element
        $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($anchor).attr('href').offset().top - globOffset}, 1500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

HTML:

There is one more problem. The "#home" anchor is used in body. So when finding the offset top for this, it returns 0 (offset of the body element).

Also I think the custom easing 'easeInOutExpo' requires jQuery UI (if that isn't working you need to include it):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Hopefully this answers your question!

Comment: hi @d-slee i have just updated the code to match your suggestions yet it still doesn't work at should any ideas ?

Comment: See the edits and try this: https://jsfiddle.net/7muk9zhh/11/
Which part of it is not working?

Comment: if you go to http://wp.matthewwood.me/ and click through the links you will see what i mean the padding above the links change.

Comment: The padding on the left or the padding on the top?

Comment: no the padding on the section if you click about then click about again it changes the padding for that section

Comment: Like the actual padding for the section or where it scrolls to? Sorry I can't really access the site until 10pm (internet filtering and such)

Comment: Where the link scrolls to.

Comment: Try adding console.log(globOffset) before $('body').stop().animate.....

Just to check if the offset is changing for some reason :)

Comment: okay that's strange I added that in and now it seems to be working although that code is just returning the correct value each time and doesn't affect the code :/ either way thank you for your help

Comment: it does now i dunno what happend but all of a sudden it started working although all i did was add that line of code in i don't understand really

Comment: Well that makes total sense haha :D

Comment: Well thanks for all your help anyway your a life saver ive been racking my brain for the last few days trying to work out what i was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code: should work properly and has nice smooth scrolling effect:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var offset = $(".navbar").offset().top;     
   $(window).scroll(function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
             $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');

         }
         else {
             $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
         }
    });

 //here it starts
   $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var target = this.hash,
           $target = $(target);

       $('html, body').stop().animate({
           'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-90 //change value to your need 
       }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
           window.location.hash = target;
       });
   });
  //end
  });
```

Comment: it doesn't work as when you click the first link (Doesn't matter what one) it still covers the content. but only on the first click

Comment: Strange, is all code is the same on the website as you had  published on fiddle?
(Tip for css: left and right padding change for nav when you scroll, so it jump to the right a little bit, I would keep the same padding unless it's intentional).

Comment: @miss.emenems I believe it is the same yes feel free to check though in-case I have missed anything important out

Comment: i just copied the code from your JSfiddle into my code and it works but the height padding changes on a second click of a navigation link

Comment: Have to admit that I have no idea why it stops differently for these two links. I've used this script many times, never had this problem. I've checked your html and css and at first sight everything is ok, but I would look for a cause in a header/first section as this "error" occurs only when you scroll from home viewport to the next one. I have alternative way for this type of navigation. It's a little bit longer, maybe less elegant for some but you can customize the offset for each vieports.

Comment: link to alternative way:
https://jsfiddle.net/scr0pthq/8/

Feel free to change every value for offset (currently set up on 60) and see how it can works.